# How to Ignore Nulls in Hive Lead Function

Tags: sql, hive, null, hiveql, lead

I have the following statement in a query which works fine in Presto:

```
CASE  
    WHEN  cte_v1.id_agent is not null 
         THEN cte_v1.id_agent
    WHEN  cte_v1.id_agent is null
          and lead(cte_v1.interaction_channel,1) ignore nulls over(partition by id_ticket, interaction_channel order by cte_v1.interaction_start_time) = 'messaging' 
        THEN lead(cte_v1.id_agent,1) ignore nulls over(partition by id_ticket, interaction_channel order by cte_v1.interaction_start_time) 
END as agent
```

however when I try to operationalize this query in Hive, I receive the following error
'FAILED: ParseException line 12:39 missing KW_THEN at 'ignore' near 'nulls' in statement'

As mentioned, this query works fine in Presto and gives the correct result by recreating the id_agent column and replaces any null agent ID with the next non-null value

| agent | id_agent | interaction_start_time | interaction_end_time | inbound_or_outbound | interaction_channel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 364920063 | 364920063 | 2020-09-16 6:38:47 | 2020-09-16 6:38:47 | Outbound | messaging |
| 364920063 | NULL | 2020-09-16 12:37:54 | 2020-09-16 12:37:54 | Inbound | messaging |
| 364920063 | 364920063 | 2020-09-17 8:02:07 | 2020-09-17 8:02:07 | Outbound | messaging |
| 191918955 | 191918955 | 2020-09-17 8:16:36 | 2020-09-17 8:25:45 | Outbound | messaging |
| 191918955 | NULL | 2020-09-17 11:16:47 | 2020-09-17 11:16:47 | Inbound | messaging |
| 191918955 | NULL | 2020-09-17 16:02:35 | 2020-09-17 16:11:30 | Inbound | messaging |
| 191918955 | 191918955 | 2020-09-20 2:13:14 | 2020-09-20 2:13:14 | Outbound | messaging |
| 191918955 | 191918955 | 2020-09-20 2:44:40 | 2020-09-20 2:46:09 | Inbound | messaging |
| 191918955 | 191918955 | 2020-09-20 7:13:40 | 2020-09-20 7:13:40 | Outbound | messaging |

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are two open JIRAs both about adding IGNORE NULLs/RESPECT NULLs to LEAD/LAG: [HIVE-18145](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18145) and [HIVE-24869](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-24869)

But it seems your problem can be easily solved using `first_value`:

If you want to find next not null value you can use first_value function with second optional parameter TRUE, it means ignore NULLs.

Example (used part of your data example, timestamps fixed to be 24hrs-based to be sortable), you can add `partition by` and conditions checking, etc to adopt it, this demo is minimal example to show how it works:

```
with mytable as
(
select 364920063  id_agent ,'2020-09-16 06:38:47' interaction_start_time union all
select NULL        ,'2020-09-16 12:37:54' union all
select 364920063   ,'2020-09-17 08:02:07' union all
select 191918955   ,'2020-09-17 08:16:36' union all
select NULL        ,'2020-09-17 11:16:47' union all
select NULL        ,'2020-09-17 16:02:35' union all
select 191918955   ,'2020-09-20 02:13:14'
)

select id_agent, interaction_start_time,
       --get first not null value in the frame between current row and unbounded following 
       first_value(id_agent,true) over(order by interaction_start_time rows between current row and unbounded following) agent
from mytable
```

Result:

```
id_agent    interaction_start_time  agent
364920063   2020-09-16 06:38:47     364920063
NULL        2020-09-16 12:37:54     364920063
364920063   2020-09-17 08:02:07     364920063
191918955   2020-09-17 08:16:36     191918955
NULL        2020-09-17 11:16:47     191918955
NULL        2020-09-17 16:02:35     191918955
191918955   2020-09-20 02:13:14     191918955
```